# awk / sed : replacing a pattern having newline character inside it with a string

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sed

Files looks like these. I am running a `sed`in a loop for ALL files in a dir. 
They have variable patterns like so

Patterns 1

```
colx ) AS 
( rightsaidfred,
```

2

```
coly )     AS 
    ( rightsaidfred,
```

3

```
    colz)
AS 
        ( rightsaidfred,
```

In all cases 
I want to replace like so

```
colN  , col1 ) 
AS 
( rightsaidfred,
```

I DONT have GNU `sed`. Just the standard POSIX `sed`

`sed 's/)*AS/col1,) \
 AS /g' file`

does not work. Note having no GNU `sed`  `-i` option is out . If I want to newline char I have to continue with '\' and then press `enter` like above but the above gives weird results. Actually previous col name is variable 
Its not the same  
 just to clarify Col1 col2 ..ColN are varied names. Keep a track of these names is cumbersome which is what the `awk` is trying to do.All I want is for some utility out there to see if this pattern `)*AS`  (where * can include a `\n` char  i.e.

```
 ) 
AS
```

Exists and Replace is by  `, col1 ) AS`  i.e. I just added a comma and a col1 in front of the `)` bracket. That is what I am trying to do .
In that context I tried using  the`%` in the  `sed` replace but it will NOT work.
`sed 's/pattern/&replacement&/g' file`
does not work. I cannot get it to recognize

```
 colx ) 
as
```

pattern where  `as` comes to next line 
    (

Input

```
 col_frank ) as ( col_peter 
 col_oliver )        as       ( col_north
 col_dave ) 
as 
( col_sam
```

Output

```
   col_frank,col1 ) as ( col_peter 
     col_oliver,col1 )        as       ( col_north
     col_dave,col1 ) 
    as 
    ( col_sam
```

Note :  *all Col_names* , names like Col_frank , col_peter are *variables* and non constants. The **only** thing constant here is the `)*as` pattern. The pattern spelt out is 
  `)  followed by a boatload of anything including a newline char , followed by "as"` 
The "as" could be case-insensitive. This is actually previously home grown code that I am modifying . Some AS strings are ucase others are Lcase.

This is on AIX.

Comment: Any time you find yourself saying `I am running a sed in a loop`, stop and start looking for a better solution. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: I would not worry abt the performance. You have an imp pt if the # files is large. So any ideas for this ?

Comment: My comment is not just about performance, it's about robustness, maintainability, portability, and other desirable qualities of good software. I posted an answer.

Comment: I agree - I was'nt looking at this being "people's code" type of  code. Just   a temp code to do stuff quick and dirty . But you are right - it wont be a choice if I were to share it in prod or across the board

Comment: It's no faster or easier to try to do it wrong than to simply do it right.

Comment: Actually previous col name is variable 
Its not the same  . Just updated the Q ..so we have to use )*AS as the  moot from which we made changes TY

Comment: I for one don't want to keep guessing and peeling the onion on requirements so please edit your question to simply provide one concise, testable sample input file and the precise expected output given that input.

Comment: jist updated the question.Sorry If I was'nt clear earlier and ty

Comment: You STILL don't have a single sample input file and the associated output, you have 3 separate sample input strings and an output example that couldn't be generated from any of them. Please understand - we are looking for something that not only helps explain your problem but which if we run a possible solution script against THE input you posted will produce THE output you posted. We need YOU to provide the test case so we don't have to.

Comment: added input and o/p test cases. Thanks again for looking

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to use your new requirements and new sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Given your new requirements and sample input/output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*[aA][sS]/,",col1&",rec)
    printf "%s", rec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
 col_frank,col1 ) as ( col_peter
 col_oliver,col1 )        as       ( col_north
 col_dave,col1 )
as
( col_sam
```

There's a briefer solution with GNU awk:

```
$ awk -vRS='^$' -vORS= '{gsub(/\s*\)\s*[aA][sS]/,",col1&")}1' file
 col_frank,col1 ) as ( col_peter
 col_oliver,col1 )        as       ( col_north
 col_dave,col1 )
as
( col_sam
```

but since you don't have GNU sed I assume you don't have GNU awk either.